# Proving a language $L$ is in $\mathrm{co\text{-}NP}$ if $| L \cap \{0,1\}^n | \in \operatorname{poly}(n)$ for all $n$

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

> Let $L \in NP$ such that $|L \cap \{0,1\}^n|=\operatorname{poly}(n)$ for all $n$. Prove that $L \in \mathrm{co\text{-}NP}$.

If I understand the problem correctly, in words this says that "for any $n$, the number of strings of length $n$ in $L$ is a polynomial of $n$." I have no idea how this helps me to prove that $\overline L \in \mathrm{NP}$. The only thing I could think of is for each input $x$ for $\overline L$, go through all words of length $|x|$ in $L$ (there are only $\operatorname{poly}(x)$ of those), and see if $x$ is one of them or not.

The obvious problem with this solution is first, that I don't think it's possible to simply iterate through those specific words - even finding them could theoretically take exponential time. And second, this doesn't use the fact that $L \in \mathrm{NP}$. Quite the opposite - it proves $\overline L \in \mathrm{P}$ and therefore $L \in \mathrm{P}$.

A push in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that $P \subseteq NP \cap coNP$, and that it is assumed that $P \subsetneq NP \cap coNP$. The second problem I mentioned bothers me less then the fact that I don't see how to find all strings of length $k$ in polynomial time (even if there is a polynomial amount of such), and the fact that I don't use $L \in NP$.

Comment: By $poly(n)$ do you mean that it's exactly a polynomial in $n$ or simply bounded above by a polynomial? Because if the exact number can be calculated quickly, I think describing a proof certificate for $L^C$ should be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume the number is *exactly* $poly(n)$.

The proof certificate for $L^C$ is the list of all words of length $n$ which are in $L$ with their proof certificates. To check whether $x \not\in L$ against the proof certificate, first check that the number of strings in the certificate is exactly $poly(n)$, then for each string in the certificate check whether its proof certificate is valid, and then that $x$ is not one of the strings. This takes at most a polynomial number of steps.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't think of using the words and their certificates as one big certificate. Sounds like a great idea, thanks!